# react npm run build fails with Unexpected '/'

Tags: reactjs

The react app is completely fine when I run "npm start" and everything working without errors. But when I try to build the app, it gives the following error:

```
redhat-server % npm run build

> amplifyapp@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build && gulp licenses

Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

static/css/main.340bdb3c.css from Css Minimizer plugin
Error: Unexpected '/'. Escaping special characters with \ may help.
```

I found out that error coming from my index.js file which is the starting point. I have imported CSS files like this:

```
import './assets/css/animate.min.css';
import "./assets/scss/light-bootstrap-dashboard-react.scss?v=2.0.0";
import "./assets/css/demo.css";
```

The "/" is the problem here. At the beginning of each import's path. I have tried ".//" or "/" or "//" - with any of these, it would give me the error `file not found error`.

I also tried without the "/".Then it gives this error.

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'assets/css/animate.min.css' in '/local/home/app/src'
Did you mean './assets/css/animate.min.css'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories (node_modules, /local/home/app/node_modules).
If changing the source code is not an option there is also a resolve options called 'preferRelative' which tries to resolve these kind of requests in the current directory too.
```

Comment: please try to start the project again.

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this?  am facing a similar issue

Answer (score 2):

This problem happened for me also, and i solved it by checking which css file is generating this issue **( the main.css in my case)**, then i found that it was all about a mistake in a comment**( instead of putting /**/, i put **/, and for that it said "Unexpected /" )**.
Try this method if npm build steal fails, or if you've found the solution share it with us to help others.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and solved it by adding a console.log(sourceMap) to the buildError function in css-webpack-minimizer-plugin/dist/index.js. It printed the class names of the original css file where the error occured.

In my case, it was a matter of a / in a class name that needed to be escaped.